# Is the young's modulus of a braided rope stronger than the sum of its parts?

Tags: elastic-modulus

I know that if I have a thin rope of Young's modulus Y, then getting n of these ropes and holding them in parallel gives a Young's modulus of nY.

If I was to braid/weave them, does this affect the Young's modulus?

Comment: Holding them in parallel gives a Young's modulus of $Y$, not $nY$.  See https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020768316303122 for more.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that if I have a thin rope of Young's modulus Y, then getting n of these ropes and holding them in parallel gives a Young's modulus of nY.

Young's modulus is a bulk property of a material, measured as the ratio of the deformation of a test piece of material to an applied stress.  Ideally it measures the same no matter the size of the test piece.

I think you are confusing [Young's modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_modulus#Not_to_be_confused_with) with the spring constant of the rope (per Hooke's Law) -- and the spring constant of an *object* will change based on how it is constructed, even while the Young's modules of the *material with which it is constructed* will remain the same.

Comment: This answers the question or It shows the assumption that OP made is wrong, but not entirely correct. The young modulus of fibers or threads are not at all equal to the bulk material, the tensile strength is not a universal property of material in real world. How larger the diameter, how longer it takes too cool down and how longer the time is, how smaller gets the tensile strength, usually you can find the technological factor in catalogues of the steel company.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad Yes.  And perhaps it belonged in a comment -- I felt I took things as far as I could given the way the question was constructed.

Comment: Technically it does answer the question, that's why I upvoted the answer, I just want to add something more. If I knew that when I was at junior year, I would have a better summer that year :)